# Add NSArray To NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Thanks for you time and reading this. What I'm trying to do is figure out why this `NSLog` is telling me the `NSArray` is always null, no matter what. I'm thinking that the problem is that I'm initiating the `NSMutableArray` wrong. Could you perhaps take a look and decide whether or not I did it right, and if at all possible give me a way to pass the array into the `NSMutableArray`?

Thanks!

```
 //Get Defaults
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSArray *favoriteArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"favorites"] copy];

//Declares Mutable Array
self.favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:favoriteArray, nil];
NSLog(@"array: %@", favorites);
```

**UPDATE: I figured it out. It turns out you have to declare it with initWithArray rather than trying to add it as an object**

Solution:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

     //Get Defaults
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSArray *favoriteArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"favorites"] copy];

    //Declares Mutable Array
    self.favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:favoriteArray];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your setting the objectForKey somewhere? You may have to call synchronize to see it right away. Where is the code that set the "favorites" key?

Comment: Note that you are logging `favoriteArray`, not `favorites`.

Comment: I fixed the log problem, it was my own mispelling when I posted this. Anyway, I also added code. Do either of you see a problem?

Comment: `[[defaults objectForKey:@"favorites"] copy]` is your problem line i think

Comment: It was actually how I declared it; thanks for the helpful comments!

Comment: To add an NSArray to a NSMutableArray you can use `[myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:myArray];` --> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1408963-addobjectsfromarray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is using the arrayWithArray and here is how you do it:

```
myNSMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever set an object in your user defaults for the "favorites" key?

Comment: It gets set in a later method, I can post it if you want. I pass a URL string into the "favorites" mutable array, which then saves over the "favorites" array within the defaults.

Comment: @JTApps in what order are the methods executed?

Comment: I figured it out! You can't add an array to a mutable array as an object, I had to use initWithArray

Comment: @JTApps It was not clear what your question was because the topic was "Add Array To MutableArray" which looked ok. What you wanted was "add elements of array to MutableArray".